# Updating mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table schedules with these columns

- id
- start_time
- end_time
- per_user_time
- number_of_visitors

every time new entry is created I want to calculate the minutes interval between the start_time and end_time and divide by the minutes of per_user_time and insert into the number_of_visitors column using trigger

here is what I have for the calculation and is working correctly but how to insert into number_of_visitors

```
DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER update_number_of_patients BEFORE INSERT ON `schedules` FOR EACH ROW
                BEGIN 
                    SET NEW.number_of_patients = 
                    (SELECT @minutes := (TIME_TO_SEC(`end_time`) - TIME_TO_SEC(`start_time`))/60 AS `minutes`, @interval:= TIME_TO_SEC(`per_patient_time`)/60 AS `interval`, @minutes / @interval AS `patients` FROM schedules)
                END
         ');
```

Thank you for your time

This is the sample of my desired result

---

```
id | start_time | end_time | per_user_time | minutes | interval number_of_visitors
1 | 08:00:00  | 13:00:00 |  00:30:00  |     300  |    30   |   10
```

**Note**
I don't have minutes and interval columns I got them from the query.
I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did some edit I hope is clear now

Comment: @PaulT. There is no issue only the correct query to insert into number_of_visitors column

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to get it work. this is how I did it

```
DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER update_number_of_patients_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `schedules` FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN 
                SET @minutes = (SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.start_time))/60 FROM `schedules` LIMIT 1);
                SET @interval = (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.per_patient_time)/60 FROM `schedules` LIMIT 1); 
                SET NEW.number_of_patients = @minutes / @interval;
            END
     ');
```